# When two Visual Studios are installed, how can I choose which to open?

Tags: language, visual-studio-2008

I have installed both Visual Studio 2008 (Japanese version) and Visual Studio 2008 (English version) on the same machine. The computer's control panel lists two versions of Visual Studio 2008. When I try to open Visual Studio 2008, the Japanese version opens. What do I have to do to open the English version?

Comment: I'm going to use my psychic abilities and guess this has something to do with the shortcut you're using, so I would assume you need to navigate to the English install folder and run the EXE from there. Or create a shortcut. Without more information, that's all I can say.

Comment: There's also the possibility that after installing the second edition *of the same program*, the second installer just overwrote the first one's binaries (unless the OP installed it to a different folder, but given the nature of this question [and the fact that this problem would be trivially solved if that was the case], I highly doubt he did).